# Converting from a tree set into an Array?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

**How can I convert a `TreeSet<String>` into a `String[]`?**

```
String[] cityNamesA = (String[]) cityNames.toArray();
```

Comment: Can you clarify? (1) Is `cityNames` a tree set? (2) Do you want to create a List or do you want to create an array? Your question says list, but your code attempt makes it look like you want an array.

Comment: Sorry, Yes I want to convert cityNames to an array , and yes it's a tree set.

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, I added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small application that illustrates tree sets, lists, and arrays, with conversions between them. Hope it helps!

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // Make a tree set
        Set<Integer> s = new TreeSet<>();
        s.add(8);
        s.add(21);
        s.add(2);
        s.add(3);
        System.out.println(s);

        // Convert tree set to list
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(s);
        System.out.println(l);

        // Convert tree set to array
        Integer[] a = s.toArray(new Integer[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

This program outputs:

```
[2, 3, 8, 21]
[2, 3, 8, 21]
[2, 3, 8, 21]
```

Answer (score 0):

Update, it seems you just want to convert a TreeSet to an array, not a list. It works the same for any type of collection, including TreeSet:

```
String[] cityNamesA = cityNames.toArray(new String[cityNames.size()]);
```

Comment: is the type String comparable?

Comment: Yes, the default ordering is alphabetic

Comment: I have a tree set and I want to convert it into an Array

Comment: Ok, how about my question?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: didn't work   See this code and tell what to write :  String[] omar = new String[32];
       
       TreeSet<String> s = new TreeSet<String>();
       s.add("Omar");
       s.add("Ali");
        String[] s = ??

Comment: That's an array, not a list